# How I can install Windows 98SE in Hyper-V, but can't run it after

Tags: keyboards, windows-98, hard-disk, mouse, virtual-memory

1. Create the Gen 1 machine with less than 512MiB Ram (above requires you to put MaxFileCache=524288 and MaxPhysPage=40000 in the system.ini later).
2. Add either a virtual or physical IDE drive (physical requires you to go to Disk Management and right-click on the drive and click offline to be detected and doesn't need to be IDE itself).
3. Add a CD ROM drive from your bootable Windows 98SE iso image.
4. Boot it, you might either install right away or run a prompt entering setup /is to skip disk check.
5. Your keyboard should work as long as you **don't** click inside the window when the setup starts, else your keyboard and mouse get mounted and unusable, so only click the hyper-v title bar, or you might think the window froze which it did **not**.
6. You can go trough the whole progress with only your keyboard and without mouse, or you can close and start over from step 4.
7. When the installation is done you can reboot.
8. **You will be greeted with the fresh new message:**
   [image]
9. So how do **you** get past this error?

The funny part is that it doesn't happen at the setup, only at start-up (finishing the installation).

I just wanted to share this, because I've not seen anybody else post about it.

Comment: [Our previous consensus is that emulator questions are on-topic "to the extent that it's related to retrocomputing"](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/17/278) – [subsequent things said to this end seem to agree](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/841/278). It appears that this question is on the wrong side of the line, but why?

Comment: I came to this from a thread of this forum. I'm informing people on the place where it's most useful. I don't have this error with any other OS, if I would post errors of W98SE on probably any other forum, VM or not, I'd be flagged. The host OS shouldn't matter. Sorry for not giving a specific goal, but I like to slice things down in steps.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Because the question seems to be about hyper v, but also such a recent Windows as 98SE is only just on topic anyway.

Comment: I suspect this is ultimately [one of these delay-calibration bugs](https://www.os2museum.com/wp/those-win9x-crashes-on-fast-machines/), which means it isn’t particularly specific to Hyper-V; it would crash on bare hardware too. We have had a [similar question asked about Windows 95](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/16793/) asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recently had the exact same problem with Win98SE on VirtualBox on an AMD CPU. There the solution was to run

```
vBoxManage.exe modifyvm "Win98" --cpu-profile "Intel Core i5-3570"
```

I think there is a similar option in Hyper-V to change used CPU profile.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, I tried `Migrate to a physical computer with a different processor` with the same results.

Comment: First startup is likely actually finishing setup I suspect. Try again with say 64 ram and no network card or interface . You can easily re enable that once it is alive.

Comment: Good idea, I tried, but it didn't change much.

Comment: Sorry it did not work. Try disabling all non essential hardware i.e. Sound etc . Then keep doing the F8 thing to get it to start in safe mode. It will complain eventually you cannot completel setup in safe mode however letting it boot cycle then restarting in normal mode may help. Cannot immediately think of anything else sorry.

Comment: I don't know your requirements, but is using another hypervisor like VirtualBox an option?

Comment: It does (or did) work in Virtual Box although if memory serves the vbox addins disc was not terribly keen on 9x . May require something like vbox 6x or 5x but hopefully you won't have to go that far.

Comment: And why would this make a difference?

Comment: Ziagl, VBox is Hyper-V opposed to the title. VBox and VMWare won't run under enabled required services. Thanks AndyF! I'll try disabling sound and see if it then works under Hyper-V. Edit: Can you disable sound?

Comment: It's about Hyper-V and not about VBox (late correction), which wouldn't run with hypervisor enabled, but that's irrelevant to this issue anyway. I didn't expect disabling sound to work, but I didn't expect this issue to be solved at all, it was just a report of the current status.