# Windows 95 early build's "Windows protection error" on the post-installation boot up

Tags: windows-95

On the first boot up, the early builds of Windows 95 (pre-OSR2) would commonly show the following error screen during the post-installation boot-up,

[image: Error]

Restarting the computer doesn't fix the issue. How to fix the problem?

Comment: Is this on a Windows 95-era PC?

Comment: As the symptoms described in the question are awfully non-specific without further context, there could potentially be many different, but equally valid answers to this problem. But the particular issue the poster encountered is probably this: https://www.os2museum.com/wp/those-win9x-crashes-on-fast-machines/. If that’s the case, the question body should at least mention this is a modern(-ish) machine.

Answer (score 2):

I don't claim that my answer is the *only* known solution, but after looking through the obscure forums, I found the following solution.

1. Download and burn on one of the supported media (CD disc, floppy, or something else), [Fix95CPU patch](http://lonecrusader.x10host.com/fix95cpu.html)
2. When you are past the last (graphical) installation phase, insert, and boot from the Fix95CPU medium.
3. Go through the on-screen instructions. Once finished, remove the media and reboot
4. Try booting back to the OS. If you're lucky (which is seemingly always for me?) - them you are in luck

I hope this helps someone. The information on Windows 95 and its troubleshooting seems really scarce online

Comment: Apparently, Microsoft released a patch to fix this problem. It would be good to find the patch on microsoft.com and provide a link to it to ensure the file doesn't contain any malware.